# If, Then statement for Google SpreadSheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I wanted to create an if, then statement in Google Sheets that would yield an email address based on the responses in a specific field of a form. Here's [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmwyLpxmVbEMdGZ3NVc1TFFKMEN6d3FHbjFBUVo3dEE&usp=sharing). I would like for the room preference column (FormResponses1!K) to generate an email address (Staff!A) based on the criteria in (Staff!C:P). That way I can get an email address for the point person in charge of scheduling a room.

I attempted to form a test logic for just one of the room schedulers to no avail (parse error): =if(K3=Staff!C2:J2,U3=Staff!A2). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: My apologies, I am attempting to have the result populate in column P of FormResponses1. So that if someone requests 5016, the staff assigned in the Staff sheet will see their email populated. From then, I'll use FormEmailer to notify the correct staff person.

Comment: I was hoping it would return multiple values. Is that possible?

Comment: That's what I figured. I got the formula to return just one value instead of a string of values: =if(K2="806 A",Staff!A2,if(K2="806 B",Staff!A3)). Even if I typed in every condition, I can only get one value (email address) in the cell. Lest there is a way to return multiple values in one cell, I think I'm SOL.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of sounding obvious, how attached are you to using an IF() spreadsheet function?
Seems to me like you'd get more mileage out of calling custom function roomOwners() from the cell which returns the array or big-long-string of values you're looking for.

I'd approach the problem by storing the value of the room preference from your form into a variable.
Then I'd iterate over the list of staff members, for each staffer, checking all rooms for equality with the preference variable.
Whenever the iteration finds a match, it pushes the email address of the matching staffer to an array.
At the end of the iteration, return the array, filled with all your matches.
If you're concerned about the answer being written to multiple cells, you could always string-ify the array...

Comment: Thanks but with some help of a fellow co-worker, I figured it out. I ended up using the vlookup function and defined a list of emails for each room. I tested it out and it work.